Accident and death when car driver can't use brakes because a bottle blocks the pedal
I watched this film in France on VHS in the 80s but I don't remember exactly when. I don't know if the movie is from the 80s or is older. In my mind the movie is like 1982 and I watched it in like 1986 but really I could be so wrong.

In this movie there's some kind of big race with a lot of cars, it probably happens across the country, but my memories are not clear.
In one scene someone repairs a car on the road side - the person is under the car.
Another car comes fast. Inside, someone who was drinking drops their bottle. The bottle goes under the brake pedal just when the driver needs to stop in order to avoid crashing into the one doing the repairs.
Of course the driver can't use the brakes because the bottle blocks the pedal. The accident happens and the repair guy is crushed under his car.

I thought this was in Cannonball, because I probably rented and watched the VHS at the same period, but friends tell me it's not in it. I am not sure, though, it really sounds like Cannonball - although, indeed, I've found nothing with these keywords.
I don't want to rent/buy Cannonball I, II & III just to check this, and anyway, this scene could very well be from a whole different movie....
Any idea?

I googled bottle-under-brake and found a reference to Final Destination 2.  Don't know if that helps.

@DavidDubois Thanks but that's not it. The movie I'm looking for is much older. :)
